# Missing application on windows 10 store

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-8.1, windows-10, windows-store

How to cope with applications that are not found in windows 10 store? Whereas in windows 8.1 store, the application is there.

I've read the guideline of [Changes to Store listings and search algorithms](http://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/07/24/changes-to-store-listings-and-search-algorithms/) and try to change the description of the application so that it does not contain the word "windows 8. x "or similar description, but the application still does not appear in the windows store 10.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Are you sure that you are trying to find it with region settings that was checked as enabled market when you were submiting your app?

Comment: I've selected all the region available

Comment: And what is happening when you opening direct link to the application?

Comment: when inserting the link through a browser application to appear, but when directly from its store windows application can not be found.

Comment: So I think you should try to write an email to windows support. Maybe it's because of slow indexing but maybe something went wrong and your application is not listed at all.